# Ionic 5: Upgrade ionic 4 -> ionic 5 animationBuilder error on page transition

Tags: angular, cordova, mobile, angular-animations

So I did started a migration form angualr 8 -> 10 and ionic 4 -> 5 and I'm getting the following error when I'm changing pages

```
 TypeError: animationBuilder is not a function
    at animation (index-96111fa9.js:72)
```

The page animations also does not work. I did search about this alot and i could not find anything related.